# Java - Returning an array from a method to main

Tags: java, methods, return

Would be glad if someone can help me with the following problem. The following method is suppose to returns an array whose ith entry is the number of times the int i appeared in array a. The method name gives the use of this method. Drawing a histogram of data found in array a.

```
    public static int histogram(int M, int[] a){

        int[] b = new int[M];

        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++){

           int w = 0; 

            for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++){ 

            if (a[j] == i){ 
            w++;
            }
        }

           b[i] = w; 

     }

   return b; 
}
```

Accoring to me the code is correct - it may be wrong - I can't test it because I've got an error thats really bugging me.

Histogram.java:22: incompatible types
found   : int[]
required: int
        return b;

1) What does above mean?? On example on the internet and in my handbook they also only use "return b;" to return an array to the main program.

2) How exactly does the return function work? Will I be able to use the following code to print the values of array b? Because at the moment I get an error as well for array b not being initialised in main... I think the error will go away if error 1 is sorted out. I'm new to JAVA so I won't really know - new to programming too.

```
for (int x = 0; x < M; x++){

        System.out.printf("%d ", b[x]);

     }`
```

3) Should I maybe print the values in the histogram() method? The question to answer is though to "return" the array with the histogram values in it.

Would really be glad if you can help...

If you've come this far - thanks a lot... Even just reading till here means a lot :)

Comment: Instead of using `printf` and a loop, you can simply use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b))` to print the whole array. (This is `java.util.Arrays`.) Looks a bit different, though.

Comment: @Ebermann Thank, appreciate it. Will remember that for the future!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should try returning array of ints instead of a single integer

```
public static int[] histogram ...
```

I'm not sure about 2&3, though.

2) `return` is not a function, it's a keyword causing you to leave the method.
3) You can, if you want to.

**edit**
Whatever variables you declared in `histogram` method stay there, they're local. If you want some variable in the `main` method, declare it. E.g.,

```
int[] b = histogram(param1, param2);
```

Comment: @Nikita Hi there, thanks a lot! That error is gone now. The second error is still there though. The one of array b not being initiliased in main... What should I do to print the returned array in main? Thanks again - really appreciated.

Comment: @ISJ If variable is not initialized, show us how you initialize it. Basically, when you declare variable (`int[] b;`) it has no value. You should assign something to it.

Comment: Ok, I initialised it in method histogram(). Not in main though. Should I? How would this be done? Thanks!

Comment: @Nikita - Your question were answered above - just forgot to tag you.

Comment: @Nikita - Ok, I understand that - the local-ness of the declared variables.

Comment: @Nikita THANKS! It worked: int[] b = histogram(M, a); Thus the array int[] b = the return of the method.

Answer (score 3):

2.) your main should have something like:

`int[] b = histogram(M, a);`

3.)No it's better how you have it I think -- keep the input/output stuff in main and just keep your histogram construction stuff by itself in the histogram method.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public static int[] // since the return is an array
```

I think you can call the method 
 `histogram();` in the `main method` and hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

when you are useing an array you shuld write it in a method of a class not in body of class

and also return is not a method or a function, it is just a keyword that we use in our methods

so write it in method and then compile it again!